# Partition a linked list arround an element

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

This is my code to partition a list into two parts according to a value. I.e. nodes smaller than value `x` should precede nodes larger than the value `x`.
It seems correct. Any corner cases I am overseeing or corrections are highly appreciated.

```
public Node partition(Node head, int x){  
   if(head == null) return head;  
   Node prev = null;  
   Node current = head;  
   while(current != null){  
       if(current.data > x || current == head){  
           prev = current;  
           current = current.next;  
       }  
       else{  
           Node next = current.next;  
           current.next = head;   
           if(prev != null) {
              prev.next = next;   
           }   
           head = current;  
           current = next;  
      }  
   }
   return head;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just have a point on naming of your function. You named it `partition` but you're just rearranging the elements and returning the head pointer! If you want to partition, you may want to return pointers to heads of partitions (the `head` you already return and another pointer to start of bigger than `x` partition), this way someone using your function doesn't need to iterate over linked-list to find start of next partition, and this pointer can be easily recorded in `if` statement in your `while` loop.